# Understanding the Objective-C++ __block modifier

Tags: objective-c++, objective-c-blocks

I need to do some maintenance on an Objective-C application (updating it to use a new API), and having never used the language before, I'm a bit confused.

I have an Objective-C++ class which implements an interface from my API, and this is used within a block, however whenever it is accessed within the block, it fails with an access violation error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Furthrer investigation shows that none of the constructors for the object in question are being called. It is declared within the containing scope, and uses the __block modifier.

To try and understand this, I made a quick scratch application, and found the same thing happens there:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : value(1) { printf("constructor"); }
    void addOne() { ++value; printf("value is %d", value); }
private:
    int value;
};

void Bar()
{
    Foo foo1; // prints "constructor"
    __block Foo foo2; // doesn't print anything

    foo1.addOne(); //prints "2"
    foo2.addOne(); //prints "1"
}
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here? Why isn't my default constructor being called, and how can I access the object if it hasn't been properly constructed?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your example there isn't using a block as such, but is declaring foo2 as to be used by a block.

This does funny things to the handling of foo2, which you can read more about [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to cut the example down to the bare minimum to try and work out what was happening - the real thing is being used within a block. I've already seen that article, but that doesn't really explain it. I can see that the variable then lives in a special place and is handled in strange ways, but surely it still needs to be constructed?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this old question. This was a bug that's long been fixed. Now `__block` C++ objects are properly constructed. If referenced in a block and the block is copied, the heap copy is move-constructed from the original, or copy-constructed if it cannot be move-constructed.